# Can't access SMCD3G router from Comcast after a password change

Tags: networking, router, passwords, login

We have the SMCD3G router in our office that is a business class router from Comcast. I discovered that it had a very simple password, that no one at Comcast warned us about! To make matters worse, we have a static IP set up on that router.

So I immediately went into the router settings at 10.1.10.1 and changed the login password to something like this (using LastPass password generator):

fd6d2#ISMCi70T$KE2s

As soon as I did that I can no longer log in to the router via the web browser. How do I access this router now?

PS. I know that I did everything correctly -- I always copy & paste passwords. Plus the new password remained in the LastPass settings.

PS2. I also know that there's a reset button on the router itself to reset it to the factory defaults. Unfortunately I cannot use it because the router settings included special port forwarding and other set-up that is instrumental to our business software/web site & if I reset it, this will involve a tech support call to the out-of-town software vendor.

Comment: If the password is being rejected, you might not have an option, Comcast might be able to do something though.

Comment: @Ramhound: I posted on their forum and they successfully ignored it (for 2 days now.)

Comment: There are better ways to reach Comcast then through a forum that is moderated by a very small percent of their technical support staff.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your router (or just the UI) doesn't accept (certain) characters in the password field, and you pasted in a password containing symbols it doesn't accept.  Since it doesn't accept them, it skipped them, and then you saved a version that either missing the symbols, or was truncated at a weird spot because of said symbols. Try `fd6d2ISMCi70TKE2s`, `fd6d2`, and `fd6d2#ISMCi70T`.

Perhaps do a port scan from [SheildsUP!](https://www.grc.com/shieldsup) or alike to figure out what ports are open, do a factory reset and re-configure the device to forward the right ports to the right internal servers.

But really, if you don't know how the current configuration was setup, then you're pretty much limited to hiring someone who can figure it out and get it reconfigured for you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all the combinations I can think of. Still nothing! Man, I can't believe what a piece of crap of a modem Comcast is selling us... Here's another fellow like me: http://forums.comcast.com/t5/Home-Networking-Router-WiFi/can-t-login-to-router-after-password-change/td-p/1030689